# Constructor by Reference of Vector | error C2582: 'operator =' function is unavailable in

Tags: c++, constructor, reference, stdvector

I'm trying to pass a reference to a vector of vecs to my mesh constructor.  I get the following:

```
error c2582 operator function is unavailable in...
```

I do not want a copy of these vecs, and have tried passing by both const& and pointer with no success.  The vecs std::vector does not contain this field, nor does is have a similar constructor.  I'm using Visual Studio 2013.  Any assistance is appreciated.

//////Main

```
myVecs = ptData.getVecs();//this function returns pts from: std::vector<Vec3*>& pts;
dMesh mesh = dMesh(myVecs);
```

//////Derived Mesh Class Header/////

```
#include <isostream>
#include <vector>
#include "BaseMesh.h"

class dMesh : public BaseMesh {
private: 
    void init();
    std::vector <Vec3*>& vecs;

public:
    dMesh();
    dMesh(std::vector<Vec3*>& vecs);
};
```

////.cpp

```
dMesh::dMesh(std::vector<Vec3*>& vecs):
vecs(vecs){

   init();
}

void dMesh::init();///"use data from vector"
```

Comment: If you have a reference variable as a member, then both your constructors have to initialize it. Right now your default constructor doesn't initialize it.

Comment: sorry, I failed to put that into my post.  my actual code is

Comment: dMesh::dMesh(std::vector<Vec3*>& vecs) :
vecs(vecs){
 init();
}

Comment: That is not the default constructor.

Comment: oh, sorry. that was in my original post.  the default is:  dMesh::dMesh() : vecs(vecs){ init(); }

Comment: `dMesh::dMesh(): vecs(vecs)` is undefined behaviour, you try to initialize a reference with itself.

Comment: Where is vecs coming from, when default constructor takes no parameter?

Comment: You will need to define a `vector<Vec3*>` somewhere that is used for default-constructed `dMesh` objects. Or remove the default constructor.  It seems to me that using a pointer would be less drama, as you can set that to `nullptr` for default-constructed meshes.

Comment: The problem was in fact related to initialization. While the null pointer approach did not work, this syntax solved my error:  `std::vector <Vec3*>* vecs = new vector<Vec3*>();` or this `std::vector <Vec3*>& vecs = vector<Vec3*>();`.  Obviously vecs will need to be consistently implemented as a pointer to vector or reference to vector throughout its intended scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I was unable to find a direct example of this anywhere else, I've decided to post the working implementation for reference.  I wouldn't make any claims that this is ideal, but at the moment, this is providing the functionality I expect.  Feel free to comment if there are suggested improvements:

//Base Class Header:

```
`
#include <vector>

class BaseMesh{
pulbic:
    std::vector<Vec3*>* vecs;
    BaseMesh();
    BaseMesh(std::vector<Vec3*>* vecs);
};`
```

//Base Class Constructor:

```
`
BaseShape::BaseShape();
BaseShape::BaseShape(std::vector<ntVec3*>* vecs = nullptr):
vecs(vecs){
}`
```

//Derived Class Header:

```
`
#include <vector>
#include "BaseMesh.h"

class dMesh : public BaseMesh {
private: 
    void init();
public:
    dMesh();
    dMesh(std::vector<Vec3*>* vecs);
};`
```

//Derived Mesh Constructor:

```
`
dMesh::dMesh(){}

dMesh::dMesh(std::vector<Vec3*>* vecs):
BaseShape(vecs){
    init();
}`
```